# response.write - does it call write from writable stream or from http.ServerResponse?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.
In a setup like this

```
server.on('request', function(request, response) {
  // the same kind of magic happens here!
});
```

I presume `response` is an instance of `http.ServerResponse`.
But one tutorial I read says: `http.ServerResponse` is `WritableStream`.

Now both writable stream and `http.ServerResponse` have write methods; [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) and [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback).

My question is when I call `response.write` which version of `write` gets called? One from `http.ServerResponse` or one from writable stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http.ServerResponse` implements a version of the `stream.Writable` interface but does not inherit its actual implementation. So when you call `response.write()` you're calling `http.ServerResponse.write()` and not `stream.Writable.write()`.

> #### [Class: http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse)
>
> The response implements, but does not inherit from, the Writable Stream interface.

Internally, the `http.ServerResponse` is actually an `OutgoingMessage`, which is a [Stream](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L37), and that supplies [`write()`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L477-L536). If you compare this against the [`stream.Writable.write()`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_writable.js) implementation, the way they going about writing the data is different.

> I was also curious what benefits it gets in implementing writable stream if it uses its own write for example, etc? (From Comments below)

Without being part of the Node.js Foundation I can't speak to the motivation but, just from a design standpoint, implementing the `stream.Writable` interface provides familiar and common set of methods and events for developers to work with. Additionally, `http.ServerResponse` is writing to the connection socket (see [`OutgoingMessage._send()`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L114-L134)) which isn't part of `stream.Writable.write()` implementation.
Perhaps the below excerpt provides some insight into the thought process of the Foundation

> #### [Writable Streams](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_writable_streams)
>
> All Writable streams implement the interface defined by the stream.Writable class.
>
> While specific instances of Writable streams may differ in various ways, all Writable streams follow the same fundamental usage pattern

Comment: "http.ServerResponse implements a version of the Writable Stream interface but does not actually inherit it." --> So it overrides it, that's what you mean?

Comment: The interface is imitated but the actual implementation of the Writable is different.

Comment: Or is it Stream is just interface, meaning it has no implementation of its methods, rather classes which implement this interface, provide implementation of those methods, like write?

Comment: No, `http.ServerResponse` uses the same interface (method names, events, etc.) however, the actual `write()` method will be different than the `stream.Writable` is internally. `stream.Writable` isn't abstract, it can be directly implemented and used, go ahead and try to using `stream.Writable.write()`, it will work. Just what `write() is doing in `stream.Writable` is different than `http.ServerResponse.write()`

Comment: Hmm.. if you can elaborate in your answer on what you mean with this line: "implements a version of the Writable Stream interface but does not actually inherit it." it will be helpful, otherwise I will have to look further for this information elsewhere.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava is the actual `http.ServerResponse.write()` method code that has already been supplied above not enough to show it isn't actually calling `stream.Writable.write()`?

Comment: I didn't study the code you gave in details yet - I will bit later. I was also curious what benefits it gets in implementing writable stream if it uses its own write for example, etc. (I highlighted that in the initial question, but ok).